# Custom paths for package managers like Nuget/npm/bower/typings

Tags: npm, bower, bower-install, npm-install, tsd

I'm setting up a project in Visual Studio based on AngularJS and Typescript and it's a bit discouraging that I have to deal with yet another package manager as soon as I need to install dependencies.

The issue I have is that package managers require files containing dependencies to be located in a particular place.

Let's take npm for example.
I place packages.json at **./SolutionDirectory/MyApp.Web/**
But when I run **npm install**, I just get **ENOENT: No such file or directory.** because cwd is ./SolutionDirectory

It works fine if I'm doing cd ./SolutionDirectory/MyApp.Web and run npm install after that.

For bower I was able to handle similar issue by just passing additional arguments like:

**bower install --config.cwd=./SolutionDirectory/MyApp.Web/app/lib --config.directory=vendor**

This command just gets bower.json from ./SolutionDirectory/MyApp.Web/app/lib and installs packages to ./SolutionDirectory/MyApp.Web/app/lib/vendor

1. Is there a way to have same thing to pass packages.json location to npm before it installs?
2. Is there a way to pass typings.json location to typings before it installs? to pass target directory location for typings installed?
3. Is the same doable for Nuget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For npm:**

`npm install <folder>`

`<folder>` is the path to the folder which contains the `package.json` file.

**For typings:**

`typings install [<name>=]<location>`

`<location>` is the path to the `typings.json`

**For NuGet:**

`nuget install packageId|pathToPackagesConfig [options]`

`pathToPackagesConfig` is the path to the `packages.config` file.

So, to answer the question, yes it's possible to specify a path to the config file's location for all of these package managers.

Comment: Hmm...Tried that npm command and it didn't work neither reltive nor absolute path. However I get another error now. My package.json looks as following:                                                                                              {
   "name": "myapp",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",

   "devDependencies": {
      "gulp": "3.9.0",
      "gulp-sass": "latest",
      "gulp-watch": "4.3.5"
   }
} and the error is: npm : npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
At line:1 char:1

Comment: reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install, https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/commands.md, https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference

Comment: @AlexanderEfimov seems like this is a known issue, here you might find some suggestions on how to solve it: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9204

Answer (score 1):

1. Is there a way to have same thing to pass packages.json location to npm before it installs?

No, there isn't. Currently there is no way to overwrite `cwd` value in npm. You should move directory and run it:

```
`$ cd SolutionDirectory/MyApp.Web/ && npm install`
```

Here is the similar discussion to this: https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/10958

2. Is there a way to pass typings.json location to typings before it installs? to pass target directory location for typings installed?

Technically yes, but I guess you'd like to just do `typings install` with `typings.json`. How about to put `typings.json` to the same path with `package.json` and use [npm lifecycle script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)?

```
$ ls
package.json typings.json
$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typings": "^0.7.12"
  }
}
$ npm install
=> after npm install, typings install will start with typings.json
```

3. Is the same doable for Nuget?

Nuget is also package manager, so it should has similar features, like `nuget mirror` command can be `npm config set registry` and `nuget locales` can be `npm cache` I guess. Technically it's a different software, but I think understanding about both softwares is good way to know the concept and summary of each others.